# How can I burn multiple non-bootable ISOs to a DVD?

Tags: dvd, iso-image, microsoft-office-2003

I have an all-in-one ISO of Office 2003 downloaded from [here on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Office2003AllInOne). This ISO includes the files from different Office 2003 products organised in folders, plus some extras. I have made ISOs out of each folder. Is there a way I can burn these ISOs to one DVD-R and have a selection menu, instead of wasting five discs? The ISOs combined are small enough for DVDs to handle and still have a sizeable amount of free space.

If it is relevant, I used the latest version of PowerISO to make these images.

Comment: Yes, you can put them on a DVD-R for sure!  If you want to add the ISOs AS ISOs, you will need to mount them as needed.. I don't think a menu is feasible unless you write the menu program yourself and have it mount them for you.  Mounting ISOs is no big deal..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I meant trying to somehow get the files off the ISOs onto a DVD and have them separate, but on the same disc; would a batch file CD'ing to a specified folder and launching setup.exe work?

Comment: depends on the setup programs on the ISOs (I was a setup dev for many MANY years).. if they are using a relative path (which is likely).. copying the stuff into folders on the DVD should work fine.  Why use a batch file?  Just open the sub-folder and run setup..